# Match individual instances using RegEx

Tags: ruby, regex

I'll be brief

```
"Test(this)thingplease(for)me"[/\(.*\)/]
```

matches

Test **(this)thingplease(for)** me

I want

Test **(this)** thingplease **(for)** me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use non greedy regex, i.e.: `\(.*?\)` or this: `\([^()]*\)`

It will match:

1. `(this)`
2. `(for)`

Answer (score 2):

Try making the match non-greedy by adding a ? after the *:

`/\(.*?\)/`

Otherwise try

`/\([^)]*\)/`